# Unable to search for Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, rfkill

After I switch on Bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04, it's not able to search any devices.

I ran `rfkill list`, and all was unblocked.

```
rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Actually on seeing the status of Bluetooth, I got an rfkill error

```
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-27 13:12:47 IST; 5min ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 940 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
        Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─940 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Starting SDP server
Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 27 13:12:47 shubham-Inspiron-3542 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 27 13:12:57 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Dec 27 13:13:32 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 27 13:13:32 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 27 13:13:36 shubham-Inspiron-3542 bluetoothd[940]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Kindly help on this. I even tried updating the firmware, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have already answered similar question here askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: @Tejas - ur answer didn't work... As I asked in question.. my ubuntu is unable to search any device itself!!